# Appending imgs to d3 force graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a d3 force graph with countries' flags, using a spritesheet for the imgs.

I guess I'm still having a hard time understanding d3 syntactically. I was going to use a background-image from a css flag class, and then the subimages would have background-positions. However, adding an img with a class, as in:

```
var nodesDrawn = d3
  .select("#container")
  .selectAll("img")
    .data(nodesData)
    .enter()
    .append("img")
    .attr('class', function(d){return "flag flag-"+d.code;})
    ;
```

produces images, but doesn't work with the force graph... [force nodes without links](https://jsfiddle.net/asparism/xegcs4pL/2/)

Alternatively I have produced the graph itself, and do have nodes that work, but can't use images instead of svg circles... [force links without nodes](https://jsfiddle.net/asparism/Lv8kt52z/1/)

```
var nodesDrawn = svg
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("img")
    .data(nodesData)
    .enter()
    .append("img")
    .attr('class', function(d){return "flag flag-"+d.code;})
    ;
```

And you can see that with links but not nodes, I'm trying to append the nodes to an svg, whereas the working images are being appended to the body directly. Can anyone help me understand how this works?

Comment: There is a 403 for the flags' png. Please fix that, then we can better help you.

Comment: How would I do that? The link works fine for me. Are you not able to see the flags in the jsfiddle?

Comment: No, I'm not. If you're seeing them, then ignore my comment, since you're not getting the 403. I hope someone else can help you.

Comment: Also getting a 403 on https://media.flag-sprites.com/zrurcf/flags.png, but it loads fine as a single request in the browser.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509228/flag-sprites-not-rendering-in-d3-force-layout) question help at all?

Answer (score 0):

`img` is an HTML tag, and the graph you're building is SVG. Once you start working inside of a `svg` tag on a page, you're dealing with [SVG elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element), not HTML elements.

You can, though,

1. Put HTML inside of SVG by using the [foreignObject tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)
2. Use the SVG equivalent of the `img` tag, which is the [`image` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag)

Comment: Should I be able to simply append images instead of nodes, or will I also need to restructure my code if I go that route?